# In an Asset field, how to use a dynamic subfolder field value that is dependent on the element type?

Tags: assets, subfolder

I have a field named `image` that is assigned to an entry as well as a category.

When a user edits an entry, I would like the subfolder to be named after the section.handle property.

When a user edits a category, I would like the subfolder to be named after the group.handle property.

Is there a way to achieve this? I've tried something like this:

```
{{ section.handle ?? group.handle }}
```

...but unfortunately it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `??` operator or the `is defined` operator do not work at that level, for a reason unkown to me.

I found a workaround: testing against a property which I know will always be there. In our case, we know that the field will only be assigned to a category or an entry. Thus, we can check if the element type is a category and use the group handle as subfolder or the entry's section handle if it is an entry:

```
{% if object.elementType == 'Category' %}{group.handle}{% else %}{section.handle}{% endif %}
```

I don't know if it is the best solution, but it works.

Comment: This sadly doesn't work any longer in the new Craft 3. It'd be nice to find a solution that did. For now I've created one field for my categories and one for my entries.